# What is the Dart representation of AnyClass in Swift

Tags: swift, flutter, dart

I am trying to mirror my implementation in Swift into Dart and want to have a variable that will hold a returnType which in Swift would be a AnyClass like this:

```
AnyClass returnType
```

How do I do this in Dart? Is it even possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object` or `dynamic`

```dart
Object returnType;
```